# SSMS registered Servers

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am currently trying to migrate my ssms registered servers from one machine to another.  This is complicated by the fact that I am running ssms 17 on the source, and ssms 16 on the destination.  I would run 17 on the second computer but it is only a 32 bit machine, so i am sol for that.

I have well over 100 machines saved so I am hoping there is some way to move the configuration rather then have to start building it from scratch.

Comment: Have you tried export/import?  I don't believe the format has changed in a while?

Comment: I did try export import and it isn't working.  im not sure if its a 17.x vs 16.x issue or a 32bit vs 64bit issue, but it fails.

Comment: If I have time I'll try to do this sometime this week but you could try adding one or two servers on 17, export, do the same on 16 then do a compare.  See what the differences are and manually change the 17 export (search and replace, etc)

Comment: Comparing the xml files seems exceptionally painful, but not as painful as re-registering all the servers. I might have to resort to this. If I go down this road, I'll update the post

Comment: I was thinking in terms of doing a file compare of the 2 files.  Just one or two registrations in each.  Just to find the differences so you can do search and replaces to fix them.

Answer (score 2):

You should use dbatools - [Copy-DbaRegServer](https://docs.dbatools.io/Copy-DbaRegServer)

> This command copies all groups, subgroups, and registered servers from one SQL Server to another. By default, all objects are copied.
>
> To migrate all groups, subgroups, and server instances are copied from sqlserver’s Central Management Server to sqlcluster’s Central Management Server.

```
Copy-DbaRegServer -Source sqlserver -Destination sqlcluster
```

Comment: I am not using a Central Management server though, just local server groups in ssms.  Is there a variation of this that works with the local server groups/registered servers?

Answer (score 1):

1. In SSMS open the **Registered Servers** tab.
2. On the **Local Server Groups** perform a right-click to bring up the menu and then navigate through tree until you reach the **Export** option:

   [image: Local Server Groups Context Menu : Tasks | Export ...]
3. Assign a name:

   [image: Export Registered Servers | Export File | Enter name]

   e.g. `C:\temp\My_Local_Server_Groups.regsrvr`
4. On your new server open the **Registered Servers** tab.
5. Open up the context menu on the **Local Serer Groups** branch and navigate to the **Import...** option. (see screen shot from step 2)
6. Select your previously create file and hit OK:

   [image: Import Registered Servers Dialog | Import File:]

There you go.